# How to deal with NA when using cut()?

Tags: r, na

I have two binary files with (1440*720) the same dimensions: I want to take the average of my first file based on the  the second file values (intervals),the values of this file range from 1 to 7. whenever the values in the second file range between 0-1, calculate the corresponding average in the first file and return the result,do the same thing with 2-3,3-4,5-6,7-8.no data values are assigned as NA.

1- to read the first file :

```
   conne <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
  corr<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

2- to read the second file :

```
    conne1<- file("C:\\use.bin","rb")
   cus<- readBin(conne1, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)

       cusBREAK <- cut(cus,10:80))
      (corrMEAN <- aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean))
```

But I got NAs,this mean that if there is NA in one of the pixels, will return the mean as NA.

```
        (corrMEAN <- aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean))
      Group.1   x
     1   (0,1] NaN
     2   (1,2] NaN
     3   (2,3] NaN
     4   (3,4] NaN
     5   (4,5] NaN
```

Comment: Use the `na.rm` parameter of `mean`?

Comment: `aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean, na.rm=TRUE)` possibly. I cannot test if your code works since you provide no example data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you need to tell the `mean` function to omit `NA` values:

```
aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```